# How would I transpose SQL: Sum Case Script in Redshift and is it possible to Join to information table?

Tags: sql, count, pivot, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I currently have a script that counts the number of null records in each column. The script is below

```
select  sum(case when id is null then 1 else 0 end)id , sum(case when createddate is null then 1 else 0 end)createddate from schema_name.Table_name
```

The results come over like

```
|id|createddate|
|0 |    5      |
```

Is there a way to transpose this to get the results like

```
|id          | 0 |
|created date| 5|
```

Lastly, if this is possible would I be able to join this to the information table (SVV_TABLE_INFO)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select 'id', count(*)
from t
where id is null
union all
select 'createddate', count(*)
from t
where createddate is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `union all`:

```
select 'id' as what, count(*) as cnt from table_name where id is null
union all
select 'createddate', count(*) from table_name where createddate is null
```

***If*** you have a situation where both columns are never both `null` on the same row, you can use aggregation:

```
select case when id is null then 'id' else 'createddate' end as what, count(*)
from mytable t
where id is null or createddate is null
group by case when id is null then 'id' else 'createddate' end
```